# How can I register a custom json deserializer/parser in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Should I use filters or interceptors to meet the requirements, isn't there a simpler way?

**UPDATE:**
Looks like that my old code worked just fine, I've inadvertently edited the resources.groovy and invalidated the bean definition

```
resources.groovy
================

beans = {
    dateConverter DateConverter
}

BootStrap.groovy
================

class BootStrap {
    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
       def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
       def dataBinder = ctx.getBean(org.grails.databinding.SimpleDataBinder)
       dataBinder.conversionHelpers[Date] = [ctx.getBean('dateConverter')]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change it globally you can do something like this:

```
    class Foo {
        String name
    }
```

and in `Bootstrap.groovy` (or whatever place you prefer):

```
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Foo) {
        [name:it.name()]
    }
```

If you need it only in special cases the easiest (in my experience) is to create a map and convert it to JSON

```
[name:'foo'] as JSON
```

*Update*

`@BindUsing`does work for command objects too..

```
class FooController {
    def foo (FooCmd bind) {
       render (text: "${bind.foo}")
    }
}

class FooCmd {
    @BindUsing({ obj, src ->
        "@BindUsing ${src['foo']}"
    })
    String foo
}

curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foo":"FOO!!!!"}' http://localhost:8080/Stackoverflow/Foo/foo
```

Comment: Thanks! But what I'm looking for is a way to unmarshall/demarshall/deserialize the json input not the other way.

Comment: Ups, sorry, obviously I got this wrong. ;-) Do you know about  [`@BindUsing`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding)?

Comment: Yeah, and used it to no avail, it's for html form bindings.

Comment: You can do this:

    class FooController {
        def foo (FooCmd bind) {
           render (text: "${bind.foo}")
        }
    }

    class FooCmd {
        @BindUsing({ obj, src ->
            "@BindUsing ${src['foo']}"
        })
        String foo
    }

    curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foo":"FOO!!!!"}' http://localhost:8080/Stackoverflow/Foo/foo

Comment: Ah, messed up the previous comment and can't edit it anymore.

I added a deserialization example with `@BindUsing` placed on a command object. It does bind the json from the post body.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll check it out tomorrow when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: Is there a way to do it application wide?

Comment: You can place the annotation on the class with a parameter class that implements BindingHelper. So it is at least class wide.

Comment: I meant e.g. for every property of type Date, do a specific conversion!

Comment: ok, then i guess you are looking for "custom data converters", see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding. If it is date only you can configure additional formats. That is described in the section directly after the custom converters.